# Multi Range Slider that supports Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, sass

I am creating a multi range slider, using 2 slider and making them go on top of each other.

I have successfully created it and supported it in Chrome and Mozilla, but I cant seem to support Edge.

The styling is in SCSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style lang="scss">
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .item-value {
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;

            &::before {
               content: '';
               height: 5px;
               background: #000;
               width: 100%;
               background: #ddd;
               border-radius: 3px;
           }

            .min-range, .max-range {
                height: 25px;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                outline: none;
                background: transparent;
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                -moz-appearance: none;
                pointer-events: none; // Prevent mouse interaction on the range slider.
                position: absolute;

                /* For Webkit Browsers (Chrome) */
                &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
                    cursor: default;
                    height: 5px;
                    outline: 0;
                    appearance: none;
                    background: #ddd;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    position: relative;
                }

                &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
                    -webkit-appearance: none;
                    pointer-events: all;
                    background: $red;
                    width: 25px;
                    height: 25px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    top: -10px;
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 10;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                /* For Mozilla Browsers */
                &::-moz-range-track {
                    opacity: 0;
                    pointer-events: none;
                }

                &::-moz-range-thumb {
                    -webkit-appearance: none;
                    pointer-events: all;
                    background: $red;
                    width: 25px;
                    height: 25px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    top: -5px;
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 10;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    border: 0;
                }

                /* For Edge Browsers */
                &::-ms-track {
                    pointer-events: all;
                }

                &::-ms-thumb {
                    border: none;
                    height: 25px;
                    width: 25px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    background: $red;
                    pointer-events: all;
                }

                &::-ms-tooltip {
                    display: none;
                    pointer-events: all;
                }
            }
        }
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
        <section class="item-value">
            <input type="range" value="10" class="min-range">
            <input type="range" value="10" class="max-range">
        </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the &::-ms-thumb {}, the pointer-events: all; does not work,

I expect it to re-enable pointer events so the handles can be used again, which happens with &::-webkit-slider-thumb {} and &::-moz-range-thumb {}

Answer (score 0):

Adding the same html and css code to make it runnable here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style lang="scss">
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .item-value {
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;

            &::before {
               content: '';
               height: 5px;
               background: #000;
               width: 100%;
               background: #ddd;
               border-radius: 3px;
           }

            .min-range, .max-range {
                height: 25px;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                outline: none;
                background: transparent;
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                -moz-appearance: none;
                pointer-events: none; // Prevent mouse interaction on the range slider.
                position: absolute;

                /* For Webkit Browsers (Chrome) */
                &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
                    cursor: default;
                    height: 5px;
                    outline: 0;
                    appearance: none;
                    background: #ddd;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    position: relative;
                }

                &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
                    -webkit-appearance: none;
                    pointer-events: all;
                    background: $red;
                    width: 25px;
                    height: 25px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    top: -10px;
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 10;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                /* For Mozilla Browsers */
                &::-moz-range-track {
                    opacity: 0;
                    pointer-events: none;
                }

                &::-moz-range-thumb {
                    -webkit-appearance: none;
                    pointer-events: all;
                    background: $red;
                    width: 25px;
                    height: 25px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    top: -5px;
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 10;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    border: 0;
                }

                /* For Edge Browsers */
                &::-ms-track {
                    pointer-events: all;
                }

                &::-ms-thumb {
                    border: none;
                    height: 25px;
                    width: 25px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    background: $red;
                    pointer-events: all;
                }

                &::-ms-tooltip {
                    display: none;
                    pointer-events: all;
                }
            }
        }
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
        <section class="item-value">
            <input type="range" value="10" class="min-range">
            <input type="range" value="10" class="max-range">
        </section>
  </body>
</html>
```